# Remove all leafs from graph

Tags: mongodb

I've built a relations graph in a MongoDB collection, for example:

```
{ "user_id": 1, "follower_id": 2 }
{ "user_id": 1, "follower_id": 3 }
{ "user_id": 2, "follower_id": 1 }
{ "user_id": 2, "follower_id": 3 }
{ "user_id": 3, "follower_id": 4 }
{ "user_id": 5, "follower_id": 2 }
```

This represents a directed graph like this:

[image]

Is there an efficient way to remove "leafs" from the graph? In the example I'd like to remove node 4 from the graph, because that node only has one link with node 3 and remove node 5 because only node 2 links to it.

Or to say it with graph terminology: only keep vertices with indegree > 1 or outdegree > 1

Comment: Unless you can rely on a group/count operation, there isn't an obvious way. Generally speaking, MongoDb isn't a good match for graph oriented DB operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer would be no - there is no efficient way to do what you want with schema like this. It can be by iterating over all nodes, for example using aggregation framework, and removing nodes as separate operation but I think it is all what can be done. Assuming nodes are in `graph` collection it could be something like below but it is far from effective:

```
db.graph.aggregate(
        {$project: {index: {$const: [0, 1]}, user_id: 1, follower_id: 1}},
        {$unwind: "$index"},
        {$project: {id: {$cond: [{$eq: ["$index", 0 ]}, "$user_id", "$follower_id"]} }},
        {$group: {_id: "$id", count: {$sum: 1}}},
        {$match: {count: {$lte: 1}}}
).result.forEach(function(node) { db.graph.remove({user_id: node._id});})
```

You could use more document-like schema if you want operations like this to be efficient.

```
{
    user_id: 1,
    follows: [2, 3],
    followed_by: [2]
}
```

Comment: +1 for zero323's answer. MongoDB SHOULD be used like that. If you can't change the schema, you could get all the data in the language you use to query it, build the graph then apply your basic leaf removal algorithm, but if your graphic has too many nodes it will seriously lag..

Comment: That schema wouldn't allow typical graph oriented database questions unless you keep an exhaustive list of `follows` and `followed_by` and the types of connections and the number of vertices, etc. Again, MongoDB is not a good fit for graph oriented databases operations as you cannot follow the relations without a massive amount of queries or worse, bringing back the a huge set of documents to only build the graph locally to then discard data to do queries.

Comment: @WiredPrairie I completely agree but adjacency list was only representation I could think of that at least marginally fits into MongoDB.

Comment: Sometimes, the best answer is to say it doesn't work. There are a number of well documented graph oriented databases that likely would solve this problem in a flash.

Comment: @WiredPrairie When you think about it MongoDB is used quite often in a ways that are really hard to justify. I've learned not to argue and to assume that they know what they're doing. I am also not trying to guess what's the big picture here. For some applications using indexed adjacency lists can be good enough. What is also important it is close to typical data structures used to representing simple graphs and can make moving data between db and application pretty straightforward. But if you ignore that (and fact that recommendations are off-topic on SO) I would say use neo4j ;)